# Maven does not reference the settings.xml for a repository when deploying

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to configure the `deploy` step in a Maven 3.0.4 POM using the [`<distributionManagement>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management)  tag. From [XSD for POMs (line 1389)](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd), it suggests that merely providing the `id` should allow Maven too look up the corresponding values from the `settings.xml` file. I have the desired server listed (which is configured correctly since I can pull dependencies from it and see it mentioned when running in `-X` debug mode: `[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [archiva.snapshots (http://snap-mvnrepo.initech.com/archiva/repository/snapshots, releases+snapshots)]`) in the `settings.xml`. However, when I just provide the `<id>` in my POM and try to `deploy`, I get an error that Maven is missing the URL for the repository, but when I explicitly provide the `<url>` the `deploy` works.

Does anyone know what I should do to get it working by id only? I don't want to hard code the URL.

---

**DISCLAIMERS:** Typos are likely the result of anonymization, but it is possible that they are "real" so feel free to point away at any.

About the `<id>` child tag of `<repository>` from the [XSD for POMs (line 1389)](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd):

> A unique identifier for a repository. This is used to match the repository to configuration in the `settings.xml` file, for example.

From my `settings.xml`:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>archiva_dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
            <name>Initech Internal Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://snap-mvnrepo.initech.com/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```

From my (failing) `pom.xml`:

```xml
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
    <!--
        <name>Initech Internal Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://snap-mvnrepo.initech.com/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
    -->         
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create release distribution repository for com.initech.ws:initechws:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getReleaseArtifactRepository(MavenProject.java:1853)
        at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getDistributionManagementArtifactRepository(MavenProject.java:1377)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.getDeploymentRepository(DeployMojo.java:227)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidRepositoryException: URL missing for repository archiva.snapshots
        at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem.buildArtifactRepository(LegacyRepositorySystem.java:775)
        at org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.getReleaseArtifactRepository(MavenProject.java:1843)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/project/distributionManagement/id` value defines the `/settings/servers/server/id` to match against in order to identify the credentials to use when connecting to the url specified by `/project/distributionManagement/url`

Because the URL for deployment is very often different from the URL for read access, and the same credentials may apply to multiple URLs, there is no looking up of `/project/repositories/repository` or `/project/pluginRepositories/pluginRepository`.

The short answer is thus that you must specify `/project/distributionManagement/url` in order to be able to deploy, and if you need credentials in order to deploy to that URL you need to specify `/project/distributionManagement/id` and ensure that the matching credentials exist in your `settings.xml`

How could we update the documentation to make the above clearer and prevent future users from becoming confused in the manner you have been?

### Update

The modello toolchain is generating the XSL with only some of the sentences, so

> A unique identifier for a repository. This is used to match the repository to configuration in the settings.xml file, for example.

Is actually

> A unique identifier for a repository. This is used to match the repository
>   to configuration in the `settings.xml` file, for example. 
>   Furthermore, the identifier is used during POM inheritance and profile 
>   injection to detect repositories that should be merged.
>
> [Source](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-model/src/main/mdo/maven.mdo;h=d1b413d862b1303303d5a7de634fd89bae0d968d;hb=HEAD#l2392)

Finally in order to fully make sense of the sentence, you need to be aware that the `settings.xml` file is just the source of settings when Maven is invoked from the command line. Maven Embedder may actually mean that the settings provided to Maven come from some other source entirely (think, e.g. from the configuration database of Eclipse or another IDE) which is the reason for some of the fun in [MRELEASE-577](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-577).

A better way to read the first sentence might be

> A unique identifier for a repository. This is used to match the repository to configuration, for example in the `settings.xml` file.

But if you can suggest something even better I will update the docs accordingly

Comment: So are you saying that if I want to have multiple (separate) projects all deploy to the same repo, I cannot give that location in the settings.xml, but rather I have to specify it each time in each POM file? Or is the `deploy` step not the one I want to use for updating our local snapshot server?

Comment: You can have all those projects inherit from a "corporate pom" that just specifies the `distributionManagement` for projects in your company.  Or an alternative is to have the value be a property, e.g. like the sonatype-oss-parent pom does for it's snapshot reposotory deployment

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to remove it from being a property to try to dampen our over-reliance on properties.

Comment: If you want to deploy somewhere else (eg 1. on a CI server you may want a separate repo so as not to corrupt developers; or 2. If you need to re-deploy an old released artifact (due to repo corruption for example)) you can use [altDeploymentRepository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#altDeploymentRepository) to change the destination without changing the Pom.

Comment: As for the wording, if the only purpose is for credentials, then why not say "This is used to match the repository to configuration, (e.g. the settings.xml file), *for the purpose of credentials and transport settings."*

Comment: Inheritance from a corporate superpom is the only way so. I would ave the root-most super Pom only specify distribution management as other things can need to change more often/can ave disagreements across projects... Which weakens the ability to force it as the *global* superpom